# Trouble with CodeIgniter routes, getting 404 errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I am trying to create custom routes for my CodeIgniter site. Even the most basic routes do not work. For example I have the welcome controller mapped to "test" and it just 404's on me. I am running on MAMP with mod_rewrite enabled.

I have the index.php line in config.php empty..

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Here is my .htacess file..

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And here is my route..

```
$route['welcome'] = 'test';
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$route['welcome'] = "welcome/test"` ? Is "test" a controller or a method inside welcome controller?

Comment: welcome is the controller name. its just the one that comes with codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a route, the array **key** contains the **URI** to be matched, while the
>   array **value** contains the **destination** it should be re-routed to.

-- [*CI Documentation*](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Your physical controller name is `welcome`. So if you want a URL containing the word `test` in the first segment be remapped to the `welcome` class, you should do this:

```
$route['test'] = "welcome/METHOD";
```

Where `METHOD` is method of `welcome` class.

**Note:** If class/method was `welcome/index`, you do NOT need to append `/index`.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, that route will try to redirect the controller 'welcome' to the controller 'test'. If you have a controller named 'test' and a function named 'index', you can  route the following:

```
route['welcome/index'] = 'test/index';
```

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually, both `index` aren't required (and usually aren't used). See my comment under the question

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1. Routes in CI are cascaded, they're evaluated top to bottom, and the router stops at the first match. Make sure, then, to have any custom route placed *below* the 2 default routes in a vanilla distribution:

   ```
   $route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
   $route['404_override'] = '';
   // custom routes here
   $route['welcome'] = "welcome/test";
   ```
2. If you have a controller named "welcome" (the default one), and you want to call a method named "test", you need a route like

   ```
   $route['welcome'] = "welcome/test"
   ```

   which will be accessible at the url http://wwww.yourdomain.com/welcome
   (if no route were specified, you would have accessed it like http://www.yourdomain.com/welcome/test)

Usually, controller have an index method which is called automatically when no other method is provided. The route you've created so far isn't working because it's calling the `index()` method of a "test" controller, which is likely not present.

A suggestion: if you mainatain the "welcome" controller as the default one, and you want to call an url like http://www.yourdomain.com/test
You need a `test()` method and your route must be

```
$route['test'] = "welcome/test";
```